# Water in Basement After Heavy Rain

Tags: water, basement, drainage, concrete-block, leaking

[link to photos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1paEbKOS1rRm6U8qaVm72SRs3HP_g0XDh)

Hi everyone. I consistently have water in my basement on the Eastern wall of my house every time it rains heavily - 1.5 inches or more in a 24 hour period. The water seeps in through the concrete block near the top of the block, middle, and bottom. I have a sump pump in the Southeast corner that is functioning but discharges below grade. Other walls in the basement are dry. All window wells are covered. I graded away from the house about 3 years ago (planning to redo before winter). My gutters discharge at least 30 feet from the house.

I had someone come out and quote me on all new drain tile around the basement perimeter (In the basement not outside) but it was a quote only and it wasn’t raining at the time. Quote was 20k.

If I have to spend the money I will do so. But I’m wondering if anyone has any suggestions. Any help would be much appreciated. Pictures included.

UPDATE 1: In response to questions posed by popham I wanted to provide more information. Thank you for your replies thus far.

There is no water pooling in the yard that I can see. The yard generally slopes away from the house so there is no reservoir forming. If I can avoid new drain tile in the basement that would be great, it doesn’t seem blocked, but new tile is one solution I had heard about which is why I requested the quote. No idea if that would fix the problem, but this is a problem I need to fix sooner rather than later. Sometimes water does enter through the seam between the floor (concrete) and the concrete block, but more often it’s like the pictures I’ve included. On the outside of the house there is a concrete patio from the NE corner of the foundation to the first window well in the picture. The slab is new and slopes away from the house a lot. No water pools on the patio (which it did previously before I had it replaced. I was hopeful that would solve the problem, but here we are). I also dug out all the window wells and placed new gravel in them this summer.

NE corner of basement - patio outside [NE corner](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DDN_NhmGGBexu2TAlrtiLUmi5PteS-he/view?usp=drivesdk)

[window well where patio ends](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XwhnyZIwZpTmUtELXBZa3_714p-_aq_N/view?usp=drivesdk)

-AP64

Comment: What about the floor? Does water come up through the floor? Does the basement have high humidity? I'm trying to understand the interest in perimeter drain at the floor elevation when your question is drawing attention to infiltration through the wall.

Comment: You're grading away, but is there some topography that your grading fights against? Do you have an area that's acting as a reservoir that overflows?

Answer (score 1):

This has to be tackled from outside before water penetrates the wall.

Dig a trench about 1.5 to 3 feet deep and use french drain that is sloped and leads away from home.

Meanwhile use tar on the outside wall.